# Xamarin Forms Templated control - child event handling

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of a WPF lookless control using Xamarin Forms. That is:

- a class that derives from ContentView
- a Style which sets (implicitly) its ControlTemplate
- a Template which contains its UI

I'm using this approach so that the control can expose some bindable properties which can be set by its user, properties to which then elements from its `ControlTemplate` TemplateBind. It's working great and the UI loads as expected.

However, I have now the problem of handling events from its UI children. For example, I have some grids in its `ControlTemplate` and I'd like to handle the Tapped event on them.

I tried the following:

- Adding, in XAML, a `<Grid.GestureRecognizers>`, where `TappedCommand` is a command exposed by the control. This throws InvalidOperationException at app load with "invalid state" or something.
- Same as above, but instead of using a Command, using an `EventTrigger` and a custom `ExecuteCommandAction` which inherits `TriggerAction<View>`. My `ExecuteCommandAction`'s Invoke is never called.
- Same as above, but using a normal `Tapped` event handler . This works, but the handler is in the App.xaml.cs, so not really helpful, I need it to be in the control itself.

What I can additionally think of trying is declaring `x:Name` on the Grid in the template and referencing it from the control, then programatically adding a `TappedGestureRecognizer` to it, but I don't know where to do this. In WPF there was an `OnApplyTemplate()` method where it was "safe" to look in the template for children by name. Is there something similar in Xamarin Forms?

Any other suggestions are appreciated, thanks a lot!

Later edit, here's the code:

```
public class NextPrevDateSelector : ContentView
{
   public NextPrevDateSelector ()
   {
       this.ShowPreviousDayCommand = new Command(() =>
       {
         /// This is where I'd like to handle the taps on the 
         /// element (Grid or Button or whatever) inside the template
         /// which should change the date to the previous day. This
         /// need not be a Command, if I could register an event handler
         /// to the Tapped event that'd also be fine
       });
   }

   // These events would be subscribed to by users of the control. 
   // They'd probably be commands, not events, but I put events here to
   // keep the code small.
   public event EventHandler PreviousDaySelected;
   public event EventHandler NextDaySelected;

   // This property can be used by users of the control to customize how the  text inside the control looks like, the elements in the control's template will TemplateBind to this
   public static readonly BindableProperty TextStyleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "TextStyle",
        returnType: typeof(Style),
        declaringType: typeof(NextPrevDateSelector),
        defaultValue: null);

    public Style TextStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(TextStyleProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(TextStyleProperty , value); }
    }

    public ICommand ShowPreviousDayCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

And here's the XAML in the App.xaml `ResourceDictionary`

```
<Style TargetType="dateSelector:NextPrevDateSelector">
  <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DateSelectorTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

And the control template

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="DateSelectorTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid x:Name="prevDayButton" Grid.Column="0" Padding="20,0,20,0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="&lt;" Style="{TemplateBinding TextStyle}" />
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Today etc" Style="{TemplateBinding TextStyle}" />
                </Grid>

                <Grid x:Name="nextDayButton" Grid.Column="2" Padding="20,0,20,0" HorizontalOptions="End">
                    <Label Text="&gt;" Style="{TemplateBinding TextStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

I'd need to know when prevDayButton, nextDayButton and the center button were tapped. As mentioned I tried this first:

```
<Grid x:Name="prevDayButton" Grid.Column="0" Padding="20,0,20,0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="&lt;" Style="{TemplateBinding TextStyle}" />
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command={TemplateBinding ShowPreviousDayCommand}/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                </Grid>
```

This throws at app initialization. Next I tried this:

```
<Grid x:Name="prevDayButton" Grid.Column="0" Padding="20,0,20,0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="&lt;" Style="{TemplateBinding TextStyle}" />
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer>
                            <EventTrigger Event="Tapped">
                                <behaviors:ExecuteCommandAction/>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                </Grid>
```

...where ExecuteCommandAction is a `TriggerAction<View>`, but its Invoke method is never called. So I'm left with adding a normal event handler to the "buttons", but I can't add it in XAML as the handler needs to be in my control and I can't add it in my control because I can't find a way to get a reference to the buttons so that I can add a gesture recognizer to them.

I hope the code helps make the question clearer.

Comment: Templating is a new feature in Xam Forms, and I wouldn't expect it to be as feature-rich as you are accustomed to in WPF. At this point, I think the only templated element that ships with XamForms is the ListView, and the templates work differently from how they work in WPF (templates in a ListView are always Cells). Can you share some code samples of what you've already tried and which demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the question to include the code.

Comment: I had similar issue, `TapGestureRecognizer` with a `Command` was throwing an exception. So I ended up writing a tapped event handler in the App.xaml.cs (horrible solution, made me sad, but the only one that got the job done). Since the first method argument, `object sender`, is actually a tapped view, you can try to get its `NextPrevDateSelector` ancestor by looping through view's `Parent`. I didn't test this for your specific scenario, so here's the gist that explains the idea https://gist.github.com/nprokopic/e847506b629ecf07bc2c66659f02aec1. If it works I'll post it as an answer. Good luck!